# toLocaleTimeString on Safari and WebView converts to incorrect time

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, safari

I'm developing an Angular web application.

User has the ability to change how date and time are displayed by specifying locale.

This works fine inside firefox, chrome, android webView, however i get strange results in Safari and iOS webView.

```
let dateTime = new Date(0,0,0,hours,minutes);
console.log(dateTime); // Shows: Sun Dec 31 1899 10:16:00 GMT+0200 ( EET )
console.log(dateTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'}))); // Shows: 9:40 AM
```

Why and how is this time wrong by 36 minutes?
How can i fix it. Are there any other ways to convert `Date` type into time string using locale settings?

`Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'}).format(dateTime)` result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be surprised how many issues the dates in javascript have (:
using some libraries for dates would make your life easier. 
[The date libraries overview article](https://blog.logrocket.com/javascript-date-libraries/). Momentjs is an old big monster. Lightweight Luxon or DayJs usually is enough.

Comment: moment solved it. The other options seem to not have locale support, or support in a way i require, so Moment library was the only choice. Too bad it added 300kB to the project

Answer (score 0):

I have fought this as well within WebView in iOS. I used the moment library to handle the date conversions and it handles it correctly across Android/iOS.

I recommend importing and using moment.js into your project and use it to handle dates if they are going to be rendered in WebView iOS.